# lostpassword_redirect filter is not used

Tags: password

I'm trying to redirect a user after they have reset their password. I'm using the following code, based on [an example from the wordpress docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/lostpassword_redirect).

```
add_filter( 'lostpassword_redirect', 'my_redirect_home' );
function my_redirect_home( $lostpassword_redirect ) {
    return home_url() . '/my-account/';
}
```

As far as I can tell, the filter is never hit. I've tried replacing the return with an `exit;` but nothing changes. This seems pretty straight forward. Am I missing something?

**Edit:** To clarify, I want to redirect them after they have entered their new password and it has been accepted. I want to redirect them to the login form so that they can use the password they've just set up.

Comment: You mean redirecting after you press "Get New Password" on  the `/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword page` ? What's the landing page for the above code? Any other redirects from your `/my-account/` page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing something. Woocommerce accounts are different from normal Wordpress accounts. The code that I was looking for was:

```
function woocommerce_new_pass_redirect( $user ) {
  wp_redirect( get_permalink(woocommerce_get_page_id('myaccount')));
  exit;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_customer_reset_password', 'woocommerce_new_pass_redirect' );
```

I found it [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052796/woocommerce-redirecting-a-user-after-theyve-reset-their-password).

Comment: Please consider [accepting your answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer). It shows other users that a working solution does exist.